# CakePHP 2 JWT Auth Plugin not receiving header in CakeRequest

Tags: cakephp, oauth-2.0, jwt, cakephp-2.6

I am using the CakePHP plugin (https://github.com/t73biz/cakephp2-jwt-auth). My CakePHP app is version 2.6.2.  I have added this to my Auth Component in the AppController.

```
    'JwtAuth.JwtToken' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'token' => '_token'
                ),
                'parameter' => '_token',
                'contain' => array(
                    'Organization'
                ),
                'scope' => array(
                    'User.status' => 'A',
                    //'User.frozen' => 0,
                    'User.locked_out' => 0,
                    'Organization.status' => 'A',
                    //'User.failed_sign_ins < 4'

                ),
                'header' => 'X_JSON_WEB_TOKEN',
                'pepper' => 'pepper' // Says pepper because I do not want to show the pepper key I used for my code
            ),
```

I know that the plugin runs because I add a die statement in the getUser function in the plugin and it shows up when I do the API request.

```
public function getUser(CakeRequest $request) {

    $token = $this->_getToken($request);
    if ($token) {
        return $this->_findUser($token);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the function that is part of the JwtTokenAuthenticate.php in the Component directory in the Controller directory of the plugin.  When I debug $request, I do not get the header as part of the request.  I am using Postman for testing the API and `Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7ImlkIjoiMTIiLCJzdWIiOiIxMiJ9LCJpYXQiOjE0ODcyNTUxMjYsImV4cCI6MTQ4NzI1ODcyNn0.5hoyXltPmEXIA3eVtJnnn3Dor2lhviej31eZNbaMbow`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're trying to pass auth token via `Authorization` header? But according to the plugin docs you should be doing it either via `X_JSON_WEB_TOKEN` header or `_token` query param.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code inside your .htaccess file, it will work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</IfModule>
```